# How to get context object in sla_miss_callback function

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am able to successfully implement and test **on_success_callback** and **on_failure_callback** in Apache Airflow including successfully able to pass parameters to them using context object. However I am not able to successfully implement **sla_miss_callback** . By going through different online sources I found that arguments that get passed on to this function is

> dag, task_list, blocking_task_list, slas, blocking_tis

However the **sla_miss_callback** unlike success/failure callback doesn't get the context object in its argument list and if I am trying to run Multiple set of operators like Python, Bash Operators they fail and scheduler complains for not passing context to execute function.

[image: SCHEDULER ERROR For SLA MISS CALLBACK function]

I tried looking at other online sources and in just one (https://www.rea-group.com/blog/watching-the-watcher/) I found that we can extract context object by using the self object . So I appended self to the additional 5 arguments described above but it didn't work for me. I want to know how is it possible to retrieve or pass context object to **sla_miss_callback** function not only for running different operators but also retrieving other details about the dag which has missed the SLA

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I am having the same issue

Comment: no not yet..no 1 has been able to help me with this ,

Answer (score 2):

It seems it is not possible to pass the context dictionary to the SLA callback (see source code for [sla_miss_callback](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/34478c26d7de1328797e03bbf96d8261796fccbb/airflow/dag_processing/processor.py#L455)) but I've found a reasonable workaround to access some other information about the dag-run such as dag_id, task_id, and execution_date. You can also use any of the build-in macros/parameters which should work fine. While I am using the `SlackWebhookOperator` for my other callbacks, I am using `SlackWebhookHook` for the sla_miss_callback. For example:

```
from airflow.providers.slack.hooks.slack_webhook import SlackWebhookHook

def sla_miss_callback(dag, task_list, blocking_task_list, slas, blocking_tis, *args, **kwargs):
dag_id = slas[0].dag_id
task_id = slas[0].task_id
execution_date = slas[0].execution_date.isoformat()
hook = SlackWebhookHook(
    http_conn_id='slack_callbacks',
    webhook_token=BaseHook.get_connection('slack_callbacks').password,
    message=f"""
        :sos: *SLA has been missed*
        *Task:* {task_id}
        *DAG:* {dag_id}
        *Execution Date:* {execution_date}
        """
)
hook.execute()
```